# Kafka C Libraries stop working when I link in Oracle Libraries

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, proc

We are trying to pull data out of an Oracle DB using ProC and then send it off to Kafka topic using the Kafka C library on a Soloris system.

The Kafka stuff works fine until we link in the Oracle -lclntsh library.

Anybody solved this?

Here is the runtime error:

> sasl_plaintext://c3dukafka1:9092/bootstrap: Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL handshake failed (start (-1)): SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Miscellaneous failure (Can't open/find Kerberos configuration file)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it helps you, but it looks like libclntsh.so was statically linked with some ancient version of OpenSSL. So when try to link against another version of OpenSSL you might have problems. But this happened to me only when I linked also libclntst.a statically.

Comment: Upgrading from Oracle 11 client to Oracle 12 solves the problem for the most part.  There is still a bug when OS authentication is used and/or Oracle Wallet for authentication of the application into the DB.